# WiX preprocessor <?ifdef ?> with multiple variables and "OR"

Tags: wix

I have a Wix project that uses compilation constants and `<?ifdef ?>` for different build configurations. Is it possible to check if certain variables are defined using `<?ifdef ?>` and some kind of `OR`?

I've tried `<?ifdef A Or B ?>` which doesn't seem to work, though I also do not seem to get any errors.

Answer (score 2):

`<?ifdef ... ?>` is intended to check if a symbol is defined.

Try `<?if A Or B ?>`.  For example if you have:

```
<?define A ?>
<?define B ?>
```

Then:

- `<?if $(var.A) ?>` is true
- `<?if $(var.A) Or $(var.C) ?>` is true
- `<?if $(var.A) And $(var.C) ?>` is false
- `<?if $(var.C) Or $(var.D) ?>` is false

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html

Comment: Sorry, if it was unclear, but I am trying to check if certain symbols are defined, so I can't use `<?if ?>`. Let me edit the question a bit.

Comment: Apologies my answer was a bit on the sparse side.  You should be able to use `<?if ... ?>` to test if variables are defined.  I've updated my answer to include some examples.

Comment: But if A hasn't been defined, then there will be an error.

Comment: If A is not defined then `$(var.A)` in a Boolean expression will be false.  In this respect the WIX pre-processor is similar to the C/C++ pre-processor. Have a look at `<?if $(var.A) Or ($(var.B) And $(var.myValue) >=3) ?>` in http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html#more-examples.  In this example A is not defined but the entire expression is true.

Comment: Sorry you are right.  The examples in the documentation imply C/C++ behaviour, but I've just run a test and an undefined variable results in an error.

Comment: Yeah, I get an "Undefined preprocessor variable" error. I was wondering if you had a different version than I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78139/discussion-between-bradfordrg-and-jjj).

Answer (score 0):

AND:

```
<?ifdef A ?>
    <?ifdef B?>
       ... true ...
   <?endif ?>
<?endif ?>
```

OR:

```
<?ifdef A ?>
    ... true ...
<?else?>
   <?ifdef B?>
       ... true ...
   <?endif ?>
<?endif ?>
```